# SSRS report Paramenter Refresh

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-grouping

I have a SSRS report, contains 'State' and 'County' as parameter.

In a scenario, state->CA(California), selected and all the counties are selected in County filter, belongs to CA.

Now User selects a few other states, the county filter is refreshed with new list, corresponding to states, but they are un-selected/unchecked. Only CA counties are checked/selected in drop down list.

Can I have a fix to slect all counties all time whenever refresh of states happens.

Thanks,
Varun

Answer (score 1):

to set Select All as Default value, you have to set the parameters "default value" to use the same query as the "available values";  Like If you are getting value from Select ID,CountryName  From [Country] where [StateID]=@ID then use same query to set Default Value.

Comment: We are using:- Select '-1' as Value ,'<Blank>' as CountyName UNION ALL 
select distinct County as Value, County as CountyName  from FipsLT 
Where County is not Null and  [StateAbbr] in (@State)
order by CountyName

Comment: And binding CountyName as Available Values, Value as default value. Still issue persists.